# How do I use a date input with ngModel?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have date input box like this

```
<input [(ngModel)]="value"
       type="text"
class="form-control">
```

How do I display and submit the value?

User input should be formatted as dd/MM/yyyy and submit value should be formatted as yyyy/MM/dd.

Comment: A couple things to consider: do you need cross browser compatibility? (There is `input[type=date]`, but it doesn't have support in IE11, Safari, or Firefox currently: http://caniuse.com/#search=input%20date) And form validation: should your form be invalid if the user enters something non-date (e.g. 'asdf')?

Comment: yes, exactly. many thanks @stealththeninja.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template, add a **keyup** event listener to one input field and set name to another while keeping second hidden.

```
<input type="text" (keyup)="changeFormat($event)" [(ngModel)]="value" placeholder="Enter a Date here">
<input type="hidden" name="dateField" [attr.value]="returnValue"><hr>
<h1 [hidden]="!value">Hello {{returnValue}}!</h1>
```

In component create the method to modify the format of date from input field and set it to another variable returnValue which will store formatted date, as shown below.

```
value: string = '';
returnValue : string = "";

changeFormat($event):void {
  let argDateArr = this.value.split("/");
  let year = argDateArr[2];
  argDateArr[2] = argDateArr[0];
  argDateArr[0] = year;
  this.returnValue = argDateArr.join("/");
}
```

[Plunker can be found here](https://plnkr.co/edit/zqZZ9RuQ0zDaJqiPwCCL?p=preview)

Hope this helps.

Comment: @LalitUmbakar thanks you, this helpfull. but how if i want make Validator for the display value?

Answer (score 1):

First

```
npm install ng2-datepicker --save
```

You should be using input type date as below

```
 <input id="textinput" [(ngModel)]="startDate" name="textinput" type="date" placeholder="Start Date" class="form-control input-md">
```

Ensure that in your package.json has

`"ng2-datepicker": "^1.4.7"` in it dependencies

Your output will be as [image]

Comment: This is working  fine in CHROME. But, I dont know why this is not working in SAFARI?